# Skip unnessary XML level in JMS Serializer

Tags: php, xml, jms-serializer

I have a part of XML as follows:

```
<results xmlns:opensearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" for="XXX">
    <opensearch:Query role="request" searchTerms="XXX" startPage="1"/>
    <opensearch:totalResults>2</opensearch:totalResults>
    <opensearch:startIndex>0</opensearch:startIndex>
    <opensearch:itemsPerPage>50</opensearch:itemsPerPage>
    <albummatches>
        <album>
```

Is it possible to skip `albummatches` element and set something like?

```
/**
 * @JMS\Type("array<XXX>")
 * @JMS\XmlList(inline=true, entry="albummatches\album")
 * @var XXX[]
 */
protected $items;
```

I'm using [jms/serializer](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer).

Comment: We need more context.  Language?  Environment?  Working code that doesn't quite do what you want, maybe?

Comment: Part of the code, that is responsible for the description is avaiable. Language, well since [tag:jms-serializer] is a PHP library, then it is PHP. Don't understand what is ment under the environment and don't see how it is relevant in current case.

Comment: Please note that "JMS" generally means [something very different](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service), so displaying PHP code yet saying you're doing something with JMS can be extremely confusing.  *Always* include a language tag, and try to link to the library being used if there's any doubt that it's well known.

Comment: Last tag is linked to desciption, that explains it and has a link to the library. But nevertheless any thoughts regarding primary question?

Comment: Are you serializing or de-serializing?

Comment: Any throughts or news?